# Route vpn traffic to second iface on Freebsd

Tags: freebsd, vpn, ipfw

im switching Linux home router to FreeBSD.
It has two network cards - ue0 connected to Internet and
ue1 connected to lan internal network.
I need to run vpn connection on eu0 and forward all ue1 clients through that vpn. So all clients connected to ue1 will connect to internet through vpn but without even knowing that.

```
    ue0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=80009<RXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,LINKSTATE>
        ether b8:27:eb:9f:19:56
        inet 192.168.1.15 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    ue1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8000b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,LINKSTATE>
        ether 9c:eb:e8:0b:98:ee
        inet 172.16.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.1.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (none)
        status: no carrier
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    tun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=80000<LINKSTATE>
        inet 10.8.0.3 --> 10.8.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00
        inet6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::1001 prefixlen 64
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9f:1956%tun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
        groups: tun
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        Opened by PID 1499
```

Clients on ue1 getting ips from dnsmasq. As traffic forwarder i'm planning to use ipfw.
Actually i was able to achieve forwarding on Linux box using iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"

#forward between ifaces
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ue0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i ue0 -o ue1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i ue1 -o ue0 -j ACCEPT

#VPN forwarding
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ue1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i ue1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

On FreeBSD i was able to forward traffic between interfaces and not through vpn connection.

```
#!/bin/sh
wan="ue0"
lan="ue1"
wan_int="dhcpd"
lan_int="172.16.1.1"
ipfw="/sbin/ipfw -q"

#Reset all rules:
${ipfw} -f flush
${ipfw} -f pipe flush
${ipfw} -f queue flush

${ipfw} add allow ip from any to any via lo0
${ipfw} add deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
${ipfw} add deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any

${ipfw} add divert natd ip from any to any via ue0
${ipfw} add allow ip from any to any
```

rc.conf

```
hostname="freebsdPI"
ifconfig_ue0="DHCP"
ifconfig_ue1="inet 172.16.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"


#
gateway_enable="YES"
firewall_enable="YES"
firewall_nat_enable="YES"
firewall_logging="YES"
natd_enable="YES"
natd_interface="ue0"


#ntp
ntpd_enable="YES"
ntpdate_enable="YES"
ntpdate_hosts="asia.pool.ntp.org"

##
dnsmasq_enable="YES"
sshd_enable="YES"
```

ipfw show

```
00100    0       0 allow ip from any to any via lo0
00200    0       0 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
00300    0       0 deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
00400 4887 1225786 divert 8668 ip from any to any via ue0
00500 4940 1237011 allow ip from any to any
65535  992  283655 allow ip from any to any
```

Comment: "_all clients connected to ue1 will obtain vpn ip._" that's not how it works. If your VPN is from the server onwards to somewhere else then the clients on your internal network don't need to know anything about the VPN. Just route their traffic to the server and have the server worry about routing and maybe NAT

Comment: Yes, thats exactly i want to achieve clients shouldn't even know about running vpn on freebsd box.

Comment: What I'd expect is that you need to tell the clients to use your server as either the default route (everything goes there) or the rite for VPN targeted traffic. Enable forwarding on the server. Use NAT to hide the clients behind the server's IP address